# internal redirect in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a small webapp running on webhotel. I would like to put different versions in different folders. For example:

```
html/v1/index.php
html/v2/index.php
```

How can I serve pages in a way that the user never sees the version folder. For example they will only see domain.com/index.php

I tried .htaccess mod_rewrite but it seemed to change the browser URL as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)html/v1(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) html/v1/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will redirect everything into the v1-folder without changing the URL